# $A \in M_n$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ the minimal polynomial has distinct roots

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have a proof ,written by someone, of : $A\in M_n$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ the minimal polynomial has distinct roots.
The proof says:
$A$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ A has n linearly independent eigenvectors $\iff$  A has n distinct eigenvalues...etc

I doubt the last $\iff$ , it is true for  "$\Leftarrow$", but I don't see the forward direction!
Was it ture? If not, could someone continue  the proof?

Comment: It is certainly not true. Take $A = I_n$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you. that ture!! So how could we fix the proof?

Comment: If the proof really uses that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then it's not fixable.

Comment: The true equivalence is A diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial can be fully factored with degree 1 polynomials having roots of multiplicity one : $\prod (X-\lambda_i)$. In french this is "scindé à racines simples", if someone knows the precise english term for that I would be grateful.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese This is not a counterexample. The minimal plynomial of $I_n$ is $x-1$.

Comment: @Helmut: I meant the proof is incorrect as $I_n$ is diagonalisable but doesn't have distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, this is not true.

More specifically, the roots of the minimal polynomial $\mu_A(t)$ of a matrix $A$ are eigenvalues of $A$, but if the minimal polynomial contains irreducible non-linear factors, then $A$ is not diagonalizable. Vice versa, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $\mu_A$ can be linearly decomposed.

An example can be a matrix $A\neq 0$ with minimal polynomial $\mu(t)=t^2(t-1)$, such as
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1&0\\0 &0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ The minimal polynomial of such $A$ is $\mu_A(t)=t^2(t-1)$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $1$. However, the nonlinear factor $t^2$ in the minimal polynomial means that $A$ is not diagonalisable, even though the minimal polynomial *does* have distinct roots.